# Replace only in lines where match is found

Tags: regex, vim

In [vim](/questions/tagged/vim), how can I replace a word only on specific lines where a string is matched? For example, I have

```
replace here: foo
but not here: foo
replace again here: foo
```

and I want to replace `foo` with `bar` on all lines where the string `replace` is found, i.e. the output should be

```
replace here: bar
but not here: foo
replace again here: bar
```

Inspired by the [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) like syntax of [vim](/questions/tagged/vim)'s search and replace, I'd expected

```
:/replace/s/foo/bar/
```

to work, but it does the replacement only on the first line where it matches `replace`. How can I extend this to the whole document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `g` command (global) for changing it in multiple lines:

```
:g/replace/s/foo/bar/
```

Comment: In `:s/foo/bar/g`, the `g` is a flag.  In `:g/replace/...`, the `g` is a command.  In the long run, you will use vim more effectively if you understand the difference.

Comment: Good point, @benjifisher: Not a flag but a command. Let me rectify my language.

Comment: I am doing replacements as fllows "%s/\(].*\)\@<=\[/;\/\/\[ /gc". It does replacements after the first occurance of '['. Now I want to add this extra functionality by which the replacements will happend if the line has a string 'replace'. The command goes like this "%s/replace/\(].*\)\@<=\[/;\/\/\[ /gc". But I get the error "Trailing characters". What could be the reason?

Answer (score 4):

In order to become proficient with vim, it is essential to understand how to break down your question and build up an answer.  You will also have to learn several of vim's basic operations.

For example, once you break down "How do I delete until the end of a line?" into two questions, you realize that is is just one case of "How do I delete a range of characters?" and "How do I move the cursor to the end of the line?".  Then, as you learn more change commands and more motion commands, you never have to ask again.

For the current question, you should break it down into "How do I replace a word on a line?" and "How do I execute a command on multiple lines?"

You already know the answer to the first part:  `:s/foo/bar`.  (Some people reflexively add `/g` to replace all matches on the line.  "Golf"ers enjoy the game of accomplishing the task in as few characters as possible.)

The answer to the second part is to use the `:global` command (short form `:g`).  It can be used to execute (almost) any Ex command on all lines matching a pattern.  You can also use `:g!` or `:v` to execute a command on all lines that do *not* match a pattern.  So the short answer to your original question is

```
:g/replace/s/foo/bar
```

Although your suggestion differs by a single character (not counting the optional, trailing `/`) it is very different.  Your initial `/replace/` specifies a range.

I think that a lot of people use `:g/{pat1}/s/{pat2}/{expr}/` without ever realizing that it can be broken down and that they can use commands other than `:s`.

Further reading:

```
:help :global
:help [range]
:help repeat.txt
```